# Lucene.net 4.8: Order of adding facetfields of importance?

Tags: lucene.net, faceted-search

Lets say I have 2 documents with 2 tags each.

Doc 1: Tag 1, Tag 2
Doc 2: Tag 2, Tag 1

I'm building a document in lucene like this:

```
        var doc = new Document
        {
            new StoredField("Id", blogPost.Id),
            new Int32Field("ModuleId", blogPost.ModuleId, Field.Store.YES),
            new TextField("Title", blogPost.Title, Field.Store.YES),
            new StringField("Slug", blogPost.Slug, Field.Store.YES),
            new StoredField("ImagePath", blogPost.ImagePath),
            new TextField("Intro", blogPost.Intro, Field.Store.YES),
            new TextField("Html", blogPost.Title, Field.Store.YES),
            new Int64Field("PublishDate", blogPost.PublishDate.Ticks, Field.Store.YES),
            new FacetField("PublishDateTag", blogPost.PublishDate.Year.ToString(), blogPost.PublishDate.Month.ToString(), blogPost.PublishDate.Year.ToString())
        };

        foreach (var tag in blogPost.TagObjects)
        {
            doc.Add(new Int32AssociationFacetField(1,"Tags", tag.Name));
            doc.Add(new StringField("Tag", tag.Name, Field.Store.YES));

            doc.Add(new Int32AssociationFacetField(1, "TagSlugs", tag.Slug));
            doc.Add(new StringField("TagSlug", tag.Slug, Field.Store.YES));
```

Getting facets is not working as I want tough. When I do a search like this:

```
        var facetsConfig = ConfigFacets();

        IList<FacetResult> results = new List<FacetResult>();

        using (var indexReader = DirectoryReader.Open(IndexDir))
        using (var taxoReader = new DirectoryTaxonomyReader(TaxoDir))
        {
            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
            var facetsCollector = new FacetsCollector();

            // MatchAllDocsQuery is for "browsing" (counts facets
            // for all non-deleted docs in the index); normally
            // you'd use a "normal" query:
            FacetsCollector.Search(searcher, new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 10, facetsCollector);

            // Retrieve results
            Facets tags = new TaxonomyFacetSumInt32Associations("$tag", taxoReader, facetsConfig, facetsCollector);
            results.Add(tags.GetTopChildren(10, "Tags"));

        } // Disposes indexReader and taxoReader

        if (results[0] == null)
            return new Dictionary<string, int>();

        return results.Where(x => x.Dim == "Tags").SelectMany(x => x.LabelValues).ToDictionary(x => x.Label, x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value));
```

The result is as follows: Tag 1 (1), Tag 1 (1), Tag 2 (1), Tag 2 (1)

It looks like the order of the tags plays a role somehow, which I totaly do not want. How can I fix this?

Comment: No one who can help me out ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Goddamnit! Turns out to be a silly mistake.

I Was splitting a string by , but not trimming it afterwards. So I was adding "Tag 1", " Tag 2" for the first document and "Tag 2, " Tag 1" for the second.